# Printing distinct elements from a List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I created an `ArrayList` which contains the `ID`, name and age of different people. I'm supposed to print only the different names on the console, but I see many examples where the list is a `String` or a `int` list, but didn't find anything with lists that contain more than 1 piece of information like in my case. How can I print only the distinct names? (*i.e.* on the code below, I want to print only Paul, Sabrina and Max)

Main class

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person(1, "Paul", 23);
        Person p2 = new Person(2, "Sabrina", 28);
        Person p3 = new Person(3, "Paul", 51);
        Person p4 = new Person(4, "Max", 34);
        Person p5 = new Person(5, "Paul", 31);

        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(p1);
        people.add(p2);
        people.add(p3);
        people.add(p4);
        people.add(p5);
    }
}
```

Person Class

```java
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Id: " + this.id
                + ", Name: " + this.name
                + ", Age:" + this.age + "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a Set to check if the Person that you are about to print was already print it before or not:

```
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<>();
for(Person p : people) {
    // True if was not printed before.
    if (temp.add(p.getName())) {
        System.out.println(p.getName());
    }
}
```

With Streams you can do it as follows:

```
people.stream()
      .map(Person::getName)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this, but they all involve checking the names against each other for duplicates.

Probably the nicest way would be to add all the names to a `Set` and then print them out from there. Something like:

```java
Set<String> distinctNames = new HashSet<>();

for (Person p : people) {
    
    distinctNames.add(p.getName());
}

for (String name : distinctNames) {

    ...
}
```

---

There is some good documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) on the concept of a `Set`, but essentially it is just a collection of unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Stream#distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method for this purpose:

```java
people.stream()
        // take person's name
        .map(Person::getName)
        // only distinct names
        .distinct()
        // output line by line
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output:**

```
Paul
Sabrina
Max
```